# Cannot select individual bones of armature appeneded from 2.80 into 2.79

Tags: armature, bones, append

for some strange reason I can't select bones in pose mode on an armature I've appended from 2.80 into 2.79. It looks like all of the bones are selected, however I can still rotate and move bones if selected in the outliner. Bones will not display as selected either.

The 'selectable' icons are all on, meaning I should be able to select any bone, however this is not the case. No bone will become selected if clicked on in the 3D viewport only if manually selected in the outliner. This is a huge pain and I cannot seem to find a tool to make the skeleton normal again.

Any ideas?

Comment: AFAIK there is no guarantee of any compatibility between 2.7x objects and 2.8x objects

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a workaround for this problem in case anyone else encounters it.

Create a new armature with a single bone in your project file (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> *Armature > Single Bone*).

In *Object mode*, select your problematic armature (the one you can't select bones from in pose mode), <kbd>Shift</kbd> select your new single bone armature, and join the two (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> ).

When I did this I was able to select all of my original bones in pose mode.